# Cant input(file.xml) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, filenames

i want to enter a Filename via cmd. So i used

`file1=input("File Scan1: ")`

But when i enter a Filename linke File1.xml there Python tells me:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compare.py", line 6, in <module>
    file1=input("File Scan1: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'file' has no attribute 'xml'```

How can i solve this?
````

Comment: That code alone will not induce that error. However, if you have previously assigned something to a variable called *input* that will do it. Please show more of your code

Comment: You are somehow running this code under Python 2.x.  You'd need to use `raw_input()` instead of `input()` on those old versions.

Answer (score 1):

This is my code. It is comparing 2 nmap scans and determining which mac address is actually not in use

```
from xml.dom import minidom


print("Compare 2 Nmap Mac Scans /n")
file1=input("File Scan1: ")
file2=input("File Scan2: ")

xmldoc1=minidom.parse(file1)
hosts=xmldoc1.getElementsByTagName('host')
xmldoc2=minidom.parse(file2)

maclist1=[]
maclist2=[]

for host in hosts:
    adress=host.getElementsByTagName("address")
    
    if len(adress) > 1:  
    
        mac=adress[1].attributes["addr"]
        MAC=mac.value
        maclist1.append(MAC)
                

hosts=xmldoc2.getElementsByTagName('host')


for host in hosts:
    adress=host.getElementsByTagName("address")
    
    if len(adress) > 1:  
    
        mac=adress[1].attributes["addr"]
        MAC=mac.value
        maclist2.append(MAC)
        
for i in maclist1:
    for j in maclist2:
        if(i!=j):
            print(i)
```

Comment: This does not look like an answer. Please edit the question if you want to clarify the problem. Even if it is intended as an answer, it is not clear why it solves the problem in the question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).